# Aligning button to the right of a 'card' using Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap and thought I'd dive in using their v4 alpha release.

I'm trying to align the 'Arrange a valuation' button (near to bottom of page) in the following example to the right whilst leaving the other text aligned to the left. I also need the text and button to be vertically aligned in the middle.

http://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/mlb/landlords/services-and-fees.php

Can you help?

```
<div class="card card-block card-blue clearfix">
    <p class="card-text">Want to know how much rent you could achieve for your property?&nbsp;<a href="#" class="btn btn-blue-outline pull-right">Arrange a Valuation</a></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are not using grid: 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="....">INFO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="....">Valuation</div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: add `.card-text {line-height: 40px;}` will fix the align issue

Answer (score 16):

In the latest Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6) `pull-right` is now `float-right`:

```
<div class="card card-block card-outline-primary">
    <p class="card-text">Want to know how much rent you could achieve for your property? &nbsp;
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right">Arrange a Valuation</a>
     </p>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/D2i7JWqv4d

Answer (score 0):

Add `.pull-right` to the a tag's class.

```
<div class="card card-block card-primary">
    <p class="card-text">Want to know how much rent you could achieve for your property?&nbsp;<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary-outline pull-right">Arrange a Valuation</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped but I've now got the vertical align issue